# Adding in max id for a SELECT query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to configure to only select the max id with a limit of one to my current query.

I have a link to a rextester below which shows the an actual example of what I am trying to figure out. Sorry for the error in it though...not sure what I did wrong when I created the example.

Anyways, you will see:

```
INSERT INTO `profile_img`
VALUES
(1,24,'beach'),
(2,55,'sandals'),
(3,56,'hotel'),
(4,55,'ocean'),
(5,55,'corona'),
(6,55,'tacos')
;
```

Which are some values in my `profile_img` table. Right now my query selects all of the profile images for the this `ON p.user_id = f.friend_one`. Resulting in duplicate output. It looks like this:

[image]

I just want it to output

```
55    
56
```

and the appropiate max id `img` with it. Any one know how I can only `SELECT` the max id for for the `img` column of the `profile_img` table for the user_id that matches friend_one? `ON p.user_id = f.friend_one`.

However, sometimes the user does not have a profile_img. Previously I have used this in a query to get the default img for those that do not have one. `(case when p.img <> '' then p.img else 'profile_images/default.jpg' end) as img`

```
SELECT f.*
      , p.* 
   FROM friends f 
   LEFT JOIN profile_img p 
     ON p.user_id = f.friend_one 
  WHERE f.friend_two = ?
  AND f.status = ?
```

http://rextester.com/RLXS27142

Comment: You have to include `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS 'friends';
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS 'profile_img';` on the top of rextester http://rextester.com/ECAX16022

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Thanks! I was looking at the one you made the other day. Just didn't know that was required. sqlfiddle is too finicky and slow, so I am glad you showed me that source.

Comment: That only required for MySQL, Postgres and SQL server doesnt require it

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you just want the profile image with the largest `id`:

```
SELECT f.*, p.*,
       COALESCE(p.img, 'profile_images/default.jpg') as profile_img
FROM friends f LEFT JOIN
     profile_img p 
     ON p.user_id = f.friend_one AND
        p.id = (select max(p2.id) from profile_img p2 where p2.user_id = p.user_id)
WHERE f.friend_two = ? AND f.status = ?;
```

Comment: Hmmmm.. I think it may be working, but I forgot to put this into my question. For those who do not have profile_img's, I set the profile img to a default. In another query I have this, but not sure how to add it to the query you made.. `(case when p.img <> '' then p.img else 'profile_images/default.jpg'
  end) as img`

Comment: @Paul . . . I would expect `coalesce(p.img, 'profile_images/default.jpg') as img` in the `select`.

Comment: Like this? `SELECT f.*, p.*,coalesce(p.img, 'profile_images/default.jpg') as img`, if so it is still only showing the one 55 result and not the id of the row without the profile img.

Comment: Did I place your suggestion where you were thinking. If so, any other ideas?